flutter won't print anything on the debug console
In Visual Studio Code, programming in Dart as a part of a Flutter course, no prints are shown in the debug console when hot reloading, only the "Reloaded..." message.
When creating a flutter project, running it, writing simple code like:
void test(){ print('Hello'); }
and hot reloading the program, the print() won't be shown at the debug console, but only the "Reloaded..." message and the "D/EGL_emulation..." message. I'm running the program on the back on an adroid emulator, as explained by the course (if it helps this is the course https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6yRaaP0WPkVtoeNIGqILtRAgd3h2CNpT). At some point when I started following the course the print() function worked when hot reloading, but somehow it stopped working.
I have tried:

using import 'dart:developer' and the log() function
using debugPrint()
restarting everything
creating a new project
But nothing seems to work. Could you please help me if you know how to fix this? Thank you very much in advance.

The following is the code that I used. It's the standard code for new flutter projects plus the void function that prints 'name'.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

void test(){
  print('name');
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // TRY THIS: Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see
        // the application has a purple toolbar. Then, without quitting the app,
        // try changing the seedColor in the colorScheme below to Colors.green
        // and then invoke "hot reload" (save your changes or press the "hot
        // reload" button in a Flutter-supported IDE, or press "r" if you used
        // the command line to start the app).
        //
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // state is not lost during the reload. To reset the state, use hot
        // restart instead.
        //
        // This works for code too, not just values: Most code changes can be
        // tested with just a hot reload.
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
        // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
        // change color while the other colors stay the same.
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          //
          // TRY THIS: Invoke "debug painting" (choose the "Toggle Debug Paint"
          // action in the IDE, or press "p" in the console), to see the
          // wireframe for each widget.
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}


provide all your main.dart code please

I edited the post with the code that I used, but it's the standard code that comes with new flutter projects and I only added the void function that prints 'name'. I was just following the tutorial but the hot reload doesn't print 'name'.

I solved it. check my answer

if my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78862626/14976321 helped you, please upvote and hit that check button. thanks

you should call the test() function somewhere to print the text
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

void test() {
  print('name');
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    test();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thanks for the help, but even trying to call the function where you told me doesn't solve my problem.

have tried this code dartpad.dev?

It does print name each time I click the button, but I don't see a debug console where I can see the changes if I hot reload.

From What I understood from you in comment section,
to see the print whenever you hot reload:
Call test() function under your build method
Here is the working code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

//You Did Not call the test() fun. Please check changes in Widget ***build*** and also ***init*** in your code now it works fine :)
void test() {
  print('called test method and here is the printed data: name');
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

//Check here. When App Starts, this initState will be called.
  @override
  void initState() {
    //Show print when app launched for the first time
    test();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   //Show print each time you hot reload the app.
    test();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Further Information:
I also have call test() method in initstate to show you when the app launches for the first time, this method will be called, and whenever you hot reload, the test() method will be called because we call test() method under build method.

Happy Coding :)

Thanks for trying to help! Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, as even copying the code directly won't result in the debug console printing the message.

create new flutter project and in main.dart file paste my code instead of its old code and let me know the result

I did it and even though it does execute the print when I run the app, it doesn't do it when making a change and hot reloading.

NO NO Noooooo, You are making mistake, This code print when the app launches for the first time. I think you have just started the flutter, Am I right?

Yes, that's exactly it. But what should I do then?

Tell me when do u want to see print? when app start? when u click on a button or what?

Whenever I hot reload, since that's what I understand its normal.

OK I Got it. check my Edited Answer again
